# XHDPI drawable folder issues

Tags: android, layout, device

I have a problem in my app dev process.
Actually, I am a the size of drawable part and there is something I dont get !

I try my app on 2 devices, one is 7 inch and the other is 4 inch, but both are consider xtrem high density pixel ( both are around 300 dpi ).

So how do I manage to get the right image size on the screen ? Because both device take the same image on the same folder, but since I am using a match content, the image is greate on 7 inch but way too big on 4 inch !

Do I need to work on this, match parent, content, fill parent, content ... or is there something else that I don't get ?

Thanks everybody !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which images  you want to use in 4 inch put that images in

> res->drawable-xhdpi  folder

and which images you want to use in 7 inch, create a folder named

> drawable-sw600dp

in res and put 7 inch related images in that folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! If a have several differents pixel density 7 inch tablet, do I need to add - XHDPI / - HDPI ... after the sw600dp ?

Comment: @user1876708 according to current android device market there is not an big issue for this you problem is solved by this new folder only,but you can do like that(add-xhdpi),is give you a perfect result and be helpful for future.

Comment: @user1876708 Is it useful to you?

Comment: Yes it is ! Thanks ! So it means, that if I want my game to fit to every possible Android devices and Android version, I need to deal with ldpi / mdpi / hdpi / xhdpi / xxhdpi / xxxhdpi / sw600dp-xhdpi ( and only this one ?) / sw720dp-xhdpi ( and only this one ?) / large-xhdpi ( and only this one ? / xlarge-xhdpi ( and only this one ? ) ?

Answer (score 0):

For 300dpi phone create drawable folder for

drawable-xhdpi for 4" phone and for 7" create folder drawable-sw600dp-mdpi.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ! But Why mdpi ? I assume if it is a XDHPI tablet I have to put drawable-sw600dp-xhdpi right ?